# MySql query duplicating results (with certain parameters)

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a fairly complex query (to me) that returns duplicate results ONLY when the parameter passed results in 'dest_xdock: ' . $row['dest_xdock'] as a certain value.  Can anyone identify why this is happening in the Query?  I don't have duplicates of this in the table that I can see.  Here is the query:

```
select
`orig_lookup`.`zipcode` AS `orig_zipcode`,
`orig_lookup`.`state` AS `orig_state`,
`orig_lookup`.`svcnotes` AS `orig_svcnotes`,
`orig_lookup`.`svcterms` AS `orig_svcterms`,
`orig_lookup`.`daysout` AS `orig_daysout`,
`orig_lookup`.`daysin` AS `orig_daysin`,
`orig_lookup`.`pcity` AS `orig_city`,
`orig_lookup`.`scac` AS `orig_scac`,
`orig_lookup`.`xdock` AS `orig_xdock`,
`orig_lookup`.`scac2` AS `orig_scac2`,
`orig_lookup`.`xdock2` AS `orig_xdock2`,
`orig_lookup`.`scac3` AS `orig_scac3`,
`orig_lookup`.`xdock3` AS `orig_xdock3`,

`orig_ssas`.`ssa` AS `orig_ssa`,
`orig_hcas`.`hca` AS `orig_hca`,

`dest_lookup`.`zipcode` AS `dest_zipcode`,
`dest_lookup`.`state` AS `dest_state`,
`dest_lookup`.`svcnotes` AS `dest_svcnotes`,
`dest_lookup`.`svcterms` AS `dest_svcterms`,
`dest_lookup`.`daysout` AS `dest_daysout`,
`dest_lookup`.`daysin` AS `dest_daysin`,
`dest_lookup`.`pcity` AS `dest_city`,
`dest_lookup`.`scac` AS `dest_scac`,
`dest_lookup`.`xdock` AS `dest_xdock`,
`dest_lookup`.`scac2` AS `dest_scac2`,
`dest_lookup`.`xdock2` AS `dest_xdock2`,
`dest_lookup`.`scac3` AS `dest_scac3`,
`dest_lookup`.`xdock3` AS `dest_xdock3`,

`dest_ssas`.`ssa` AS `dest_ssa`,
`dest_hcas`.`hca` AS `dest_hca`,

`tbl_matx_20160321`.`trmnljoin` AS `TrmnlMatx`,
`tbl_matx_20160321`.`trmnlsvcdays` AS `TrmnlSvcDays`,
`tbl_matx_20160321`.`trmnltranspts` AS `TrmnlTransPts`,

IF(ISNULL(`orig_lookup`.`daysin`+ `dest_lookup`.`daysout`+ `tbl_matx_20160321`.`trmnlsvcdays`), 'No Service',(`orig_lookup`.`daysin`+ `dest_lookup`.`daysout`+ `tbl_matx_20160321`.`trmnlsvcdays`)) AS `TotalSvcDays`

FROM ((`tbl_uscomp_20160321` AS `orig_lookup` LEFT JOIN `tbl_hcas_20160321` AS `orig_hcas` ON `orig_lookup`.`zipcode` = `orig_hcas`.`zipcode` LEFT JOIN `tbl_ssas_20160321` AS `orig_ssas` ON `orig_lookup`.`zipcode` = `orig_ssas`.`zipcode`)

INNER JOIN (`tbl_uscomp_20160321` AS `dest_lookup` LEFT JOIN `tbl_hcas_20160321` AS `dest_hcas` ON `dest_lookup`.`zipcode` = `dest_hcas`.`zipcode` LEFT JOIN `tbl_ssas_20160321` AS `dest_ssas` ON `dest_lookup`.`zipcode` = `dest_ssas`.`zipcode`)

INNER JOIN `tbl_matx_20160321` ON (`orig_lookup`.`xdock` = `tbl_matx_20160321`.`otrmnl` AND `dest_lookup`.`xdock` = `tbl_matx_20160321`.`dtrmnl`))

WHERE `orig_lookup`.`zipcode` = '$ziporig' AND `dest_lookup`.`zipcode` = '$zipdest'",
```

Comment: WAIT.  Select DISTINCT seems to fix it?  Is it that easy?

Comment: You really need to post a more minimal example. One of the best ways to solve problems is to chop them down to the smallest thing that still has a problem.

Comment: I had this query built for me, and I am unsure where to start on trimming it down.  I suppose it would be in the WHERE clause?  Sorry, I'm struggling...

Comment: Just as a general rule, anything that's repeated, like your endless list of columns `x AS y`, collapse those down into a small but representative set. If you remove things that are known good, you'll be left with the suspicious and/or broken stuff by definition.